# I need to detect when only a certain field has changed in my cloud function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Check out my cloud functions below. I want to do some things when only the status field in Job/{jobId} changes and then some other things whenany other fields in Job/{jobId} changes, so I created both functions below. But it seems that both functions fires when the status field changes. How can I restrict this behaviour.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

//-----
const db = functions.database;
const adminDb = admin.database();
//-----


//JOBS
exports.onJob = db
    .ref("/Jobs/{jobId}")
    .onWrite((event) => {

        //...my codes

    });



exports.onJobStatus = db
    .ref("/Jobs/{jobId}/status")
    .onWrite((event) => {

   //...my codes

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare previous state (`event.data.previous`) of your node with current state (`event.data`).

So you could check if only status field has changed and then trigger some code.

For example, assume you have also "name" and "jobDate" fields in your node.
The conditional statement at the beggining of your function could look like this:

```
let statusHasChanged = false;
let otherFieldsHaveChanged = false;

if (event.data.previous.val().status !== event.data.val().status) {
  //status has changed
  statusHasChanged = true;
}

//check other fields
  if ((event.data.previous.val().name !== event.data.val().name) 
   || (event.data.previous.val().jobDate !== event.data.val().jobDate) {
  //at least one other field has changed
  otherFieldsHaveChanged = true;
}

//now I know exactly what has changed and what to do next !!!
```

And then you can use results to run code you want.

You could also use .changed() function to check if field has changed (if you don't need to know what has changed), see the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#monitoring_changed_values)

The above example with changed() function could look like this:

```
let eventSnapshot = event.data;
let statusSnapshot = eventSnapshot.child('status');
let nameSnapshot = eventSnapshot.child('name');
let jobDateSnapshot = eventSnapshot.child('jobName');

let statusHasChanged = false;
let otherFieldsHaveChanged = false;

if (statusSnapshot.changed()) {
  //status has changed
  statusHasChanged = true;
}

//check other fields
  if (nameSnapshot.changed() || jobDateSnapshot.changed())  {
  //at least one other field has changed
  otherFieldsHaveChanged = true;
}
```

Comment: wow... I love the explanation in the docs... If you could re-edit your answer to implement the explanation in the doc I think it will well answer this. thanks a lot.

Comment: Firebase doesn't have 'changed()' in the new cloud functions release. Is there anything similar to 'changed()' in the new release?

Comment: It looks like now there is nothing similar to changed(). Docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DataSnapshot

Answer (score 0):

All changes to the status node, count as changes to jobid node. So instead of listening to parent(jobid) you could create listeners for each child you are interested in. 
Or, you could add a conditional in your jobid listener ignoring events that originate from the status node.

Answer (score 0):

Posting as an answer because I'll likely look this up again in the future.

The correct syntax as of 2021 is to use [`snap.before`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions_.change#before):

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

functions.firestore.document('foo/{id}').onChange((snap, context)) => {
  if(snap.before.data().status !== snap.after.data().status){
    // ...
  }
}
```